# Angular Error not allowing me to update and upload images in my Firebase Storage cause of not finding storage bucket

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Good day developers, im building this simple app of uploading images to a gallery of images in angular , but im having issues with uploading the images i got in my uploading form to the Firebase Storage throwing me an error referring to a not defined storageBucket, which is alreday declared in my environment variables , both in the folder environment.ts and environment.prod.ts, like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT FOLDERS

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig : {
    apiKey: "----------------------------------------",
  authDomain: "images-gallery-abbac.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://images-gallery-abbac.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "images-gallery-abbac",
  storageBucket: "images-gallery-abbac.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "357163460358",
  appId: "-----------------------------------------"
  }
};
```

on my ts component where my method is , i did this as imports, constructors and methods:

```
IMPORTS AND CONSTRUCTORS

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css'],
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {

  imgSrc: string = '/assets/img/default.png';
  selectedImg: any = null;
  isSubmitted: boolean;

  formTemplate = new FormGroup({
    caption: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    category: new FormControl(''),
    imageUrl: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  constructor(private fireStorage: AngularFireStorage) {}
```

Basically importing all  referring to Firebase Storage , also initializing 3 variables referring to the imgage the user select by the moment, as well as a img by default , and a boolean which keeps an eye on the submission  or not of the form.In the constructor,i call the AngularFireStorage through the initialized variable called fireStorage .

```
METHOD FOR UPLOADING IMAGES

   onSubmit(formValue) {

    if (this.formTemplate.valid) {
      var filePath = `${formValue.category}/${this.selectedImg.name}`;
      const fileRef = this.fireStorage.ref(filePath);
      this.fireStorage
        .upload(filePath, this.selectedImg)
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => {
            fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
              formValue['imageUrl'] = url;
            });
          })
        ).subscribe();
    }
  }
```

Thus basically under the condition the form to upload images is true i declare a variable (filePath)which depict the path in my storage to allow  the selected image,(also a second variable is declared(fileRef)in charge of allowing the reference or path where the image selected is storaged in the storage of Firebase )then accessing the service of AngularFireStorage declared to a variable initialized in the constructor i commit the method upload(), passing as parameters the path i want to establish in my storage as well as the image selected  by user and allowed in variable selectedImg, and then through the method snapshotChanges ,which returns and Observable , and using the other method pipe() i include  finalize(), which basically emulates with the observable thrown by snapshotChanges() executing a final function when this method's flow ends, in this case accessing through the varaible fileRef to the method getDownloadUrl

All aparently works in the form well , but when i try to submit to Save the image in my Firebase this is the error that shows up

[image]

Im struggling by myself trying to learn Angular , thus would appreciate any idea about what i should do referring to this.Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not initialized Firebase in `app.module.ts` and linked your `firebaseConfig` defined in `environment.ts`

Import `AngularFireModule` and add it to the imports array initializing it.

```
...
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
  ],
  providers: [
     ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Really thanksT.Sunil...had imported Angular module but in a wrong way!!!!...Thanks